# Is it possible to put Google Analytics code in an external JS file?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

```
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));

try 
{
    var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-XXXXXXX-1");
    pageTracker._trackPageview();
}
catch(err) {}
```

Would it be possible to call this script from an external JS file? I wanted to to something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="googleanalytics.js" ></script>
```

and put one of these on each of my HTML pages.
The code I have above will be inside googleanalytics.js
Google's instructions was to put the code in each page. The problem with that is it makes it harder to change the tracking code. (We use different tracking codes for our DEV and PROD pages).
I've tried it out and it doesn't seem to be working.
Is there something wrong with doing that? Or is there something else causing the problem?

**Important FYI**
Please note that we are using IE6 and 8 browsers (yes, I know, no need to tell me)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes this is possible. If it is not working then there is something else going on.

Just a thought, Google Analytics is usually about a day behind in reporting so when you make changes it will take some time before you know it is working. What I like to do is hit a page that does not get traffic very often to assure me that I have my tracking set up correctly.

Also, you might try making the link an absolute link in your `<script` tag. It might just be looking in the wrong place for the analytics code.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that GA is a day behind, the problem is that it's isn't registering any hits even though it has been 4 days since I applied the code and I've been surfing through the DEV site all day long for the whole 4 days, fixing bugs and stuff.  

Hopefully it was something wrong with the registration or something else. We will try to re-apply for a new tracking code and see what happens then. Thanks for the re-assurance!

Comment: When you say it is not registering hits from your DEV site, is your DEV site url something like: http://mycomputer/

If so, it appears to me that Google filters out hits coming from domain names that are not fully qualified.  At least, that appears to be what is happening with my testing.  Try accessing the DEV site using: http://mycomputer.mycompany.com/ and see if hits start registering.

Comment: The dev site is hosted elsewhere, with it's own domain and everything, and is not hosted locally on the machine I'm using. The problem is that the dev server where the files are hosted has already worked before with google analytics with another site, though that site didn't use the external JS script I am referring to here.

Comment: You can look at 'real time' visitors

Answer (score 5):

i got an easy way to do this...
Since analytic js is asynchronous it won't give any problem...

include below code in any js file
(Please Note: The code i used is new analytics code provided by google analytics)

```js
var imported = document.createElement('script');
imported.src = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-12xxxxxxx-1';
document.head.appendChild(imported);


window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', 'UA-12xxxxxxx-1');
```

Answer (score 4):

Can you not use your server-side language to output the code at the bottom of each page? Have a function such as output_ga() and call that. That way you can change it in one place.

Comment: The company I work for prefer that I don't use any server-side scripting for this, so this is out of the question. If it were up to me though, this would be exactly how I would do it.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this post while trying to resolve a similiar issue.  After searching further I came across another post that worked for me:

[Using Google Analytics asynchronous code from external JS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263818/using-google-analytics-asynchnonous-code-from-external-js-file)

I had to move the var _gaq outside of the function it was in so that it became global.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

This will work if you divide the script into 2 scripts the same way Google Analytics has divided the traditional script into 2 script tags.

Answer (score 1):

Upload google analytics dynamically:

```
function loadGoogleAnalytics(){
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); 
    ga.type = 'text/javascript'; 
    ga.async = true;
    ga.src = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXX-XX';

    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
}

loadGoogleAnalytics(); //Create the script  

window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXX-XX');
```

Don't forget to replace XXXXXX-XX with your account id.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap google code into function and execute on each page ;)

Answer (score 0):

@Nikko

One possible reason is because the GA account was created using the old analytics. So you must use the traditional analytics code ga.js (_gaq.push). I found an incompatibility in using the new analytics.js with the traditional GA account in the GA website. The hits won't appear so I was forced to use the traditional ga.js.

Also, you may set a callback function to assure the hits are successfully sent, like below:

```
//traditional way
_gaq.push(['_set', 'hitCallback', function() {
  console.log("%c ga.js finished sending pageview data to analytics %s ", "color:black; background: pink", pageviewUrl);
}]);

//new analytics way
ga('send', 'pageview', {
            'page': pageviewUrl,
            'hitCallback': function() {
                console.log("%c analytics.js done sending data. pageview url = %s ", "color: black, background: pink", pageviewUrl);
            }
        });
```

where pageviewUrl = the url of the site

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

```js
(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXXXX-X';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXXX-X');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).