# New Google Analytics code into external file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-analytics

New Google Analytics code looks like one below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var _gaq = _gaq || [];
 _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-0000000-00']);
 _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

 (function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
 })();

</script>
```

**How to move the whole new Google Analytics Asynchronous Tracking Code into an external JavaScript file?**

I'm asking especially about "var _gaq = _gaq || []; [...]" part because I know it's possible to move the rest e.g.

*index.html*

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var _gaq = _gaq || [];
 _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-0000000-00']);
 _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

</script>
<script src="include.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

*include.js*

```
function includeGA()
{
 var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
 ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
 var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
 includeGA();
});
```

I've already tried to place the "var _gaq = _gaq || []; [...]" code into various locations but nothing worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be a similar question to this one: [Using Google Analytics asynchronous code from external JS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263818/using-google-analytics-asynchnonous-code-from-external-js-file)

It seems pushing the code into an external file removes the benefit of the new asynchronus code.

Answer (score 20):

You shouldn't put GA code in function for two reasons:

1. The variables of GA become local. They need to be used globally.
2. You're calling the function only when the whole of page (document, technically) is loaded. This makes the download process serial (defeating the parallelism of asyn analytics).

People criticizing the use of external JS for GA code, are bit wrong here. With introduction of *async* attribute in js embed, it makes sense. I keep this GA code in external js and embed it async right in the head of document. Two benefits:

1. Keeps the code neat (no inline GA)
2. Caches the js- saves bandwidth & loads faster

So the HTML would become:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/scripts.js" async></script>
</head>
```

and `scripts.js` will have:

```
var _gaq=_gaq||[];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount','UA-XXXXXXXX-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName','.domain.net']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function(){
    var ga=document.createElement('script');
    ga.type='text/javascript';
    ga.async=true;
    ga.src=('https:'==document.location.protocol?'https://ssl':'http://www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga,s)
})();
```

Comment: The question is if this little JS Code in an external file is worth having one more request... I think its not.

Comment: So is your code proposal a valid solution that can be used?

Comment: @StephanWagner On first request, it's not worth having. Subsequently, the cached js is used which saves repeated js being sent every time.

Comment: @Matteo Yes. Need to change UA value though. You can see it in action on http://theypi.net

Answer (score 8):

Then again: **don't** put your Google Async snippet in an **external file** because it will **block** other contents from downloading. The main point of having an **asynchronous** tracking code is to make it **parallel**.

If you use the asynchronous GA just put it in the **top** of you document in an **inline script tag**. This is the **recommendation** on [Google Analytics website](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncTracking.html) as well:

> Insert the asynchronous snippet at the
>   **bottom of the `<head>` section** of your
>   pages, after any other scripts your
>   page or template might use.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you can't put it above "function includeGA()" in the include.js. Actually, I don't see why you can't copy the whole google script literally into the include.js (without the $ workaround). This should be inlined by the script-include tag, right?