# Best way/best practice to implement Google Analytics/any Javascript in a Zend project (for all pages)

Tags: javascript, zend-framework, google-analytics

I have a Zend project with some pages (mainly forms) which I'd like to monitor with Google Analytics.

What is the best way of implementing the Google Analytics code? I thought to copy/paste it into `layout/scripts/layout.phtml` (which is used by all the forms). Is this "best practice"? It's kind of a noobish question :-]

Thank you for any response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[UPDATED]:**

For Google Analytics, follow the directions in the comments.

For any other JS file, you can follow the below:

---

For this there is no "best practice" other than include it at the bottom.

In this sense, depending on your **layout.phtml** file you have different alternatives. 
If **you have at the bottom** of your layout file (not between `<head></head>`):

```
<?php echo $this->headScript(); ?>
```

then you can have a separate file containing the Analytics code and do:

```
$this->view->headScript()->appendFile('/js/your_code.js');
```

somewhere in your base controller in the init method (for example).

If you **don't have it at the bottom**, and you want it as a separate file then add it as a partial.

```
<?php echo $this->partial('partials/your_code.php', 'stuff'); ?>
```

Finally, if non of the above suits you just add the code between `<script>` tags

Comment: Actually Google Analytics code should go at the top of the page, just before the `</head>`. You don't want to put it in a separate JS file unless you are loading that file asynchronously (which would be a bit pointless).

Comment: Tim, I agree, I just read this posting here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870345/new-google-analytics-code-into-external-file

Comment: I didn't know that (read also this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173571/google-analytics-at-head-or-end-of-body)). Anyway, the above sort of applies to any javascript code you want to include. I used to include it all at the bottom, but from now on there will be a snippet at the top. Thanks Tim.

Comment: I did as Tim suggested and it works perfect. Thanks again guys!