# Content Security Policy and Google Analytics without unsafe-inline?

Tags: google-analytics, content-security-policy

Currently, my CSP config in Apache looks like that:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https:"
```

I'd like to remove the `unsafe-inline` directive to improve my site's security, see [Mozilla's Observatory](https://observatory.mozilla.org/analyze.html).

Nevertheless, whenever I remove it, my browser's console shows an error indicating that the inline GA couldn't load…

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry to Edit again. The proposed solution in

[New Google Analytics code into external file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870345/new-google-analytics-code-into-external-file)

did not work for me. instead i got it to work like this:

i add a script tag to my page to load the analytics.js:

```
<script src="https://ssl.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" async id="ga"></script>
<script src="my_other.js" async></script>
```

and then in my_other.js file i do this:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
   ga('create', 'UA-********-1', 'auto');
   ga('send', 'pageview');
})
```

then in your csp header you have to set some exeption to script-src and image-src. somthing along these lines:

```
img-src data: 'self' *.google-analytics.com *.g.doubleclick.net;
script-src 'self' *.google-analytics.com
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative work-around, you can allow specific, static scripts by adding the script's hash to your content security policy.  (A nonce works for dynamic scripts):

1. Hash your script (e.g., using sha256).  Do include white space/capitalization.  Don't include the script tags.
2. Add `script-src 'sha256-[MYHASH]'` to your content security policy.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src) for details.  [Not supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=csp%202) on IE11 .

Comment: It works well for static scripts, but will it work well for GA gtag script? How sure we are it's SHA wont change and after some time it wont suddenly stop working?

Comment: @Arthez: Google logs such changes to https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/changelog .  It does change often enough that users of my solution should be aware of the possibility.  That said, it hasn't changed since late 2017, according to https://developers.google.com/analytics/changelogs/xml/analytics-collection-analyticsjs.xml .