# google analytis in an external js file

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I know Google clearly recommends calling analytics inline in the head. However are there any potential pitfalls of calling it in a external file?

I have installed the Google Analytics Debugger for chrome and everything appears normal. I am calling it in an external js file in the head of the page.

Comment: Thanks, I am still a little leery... are then any definitive answers from Google or someone else who has done this??

Comment: Reading this could give you some opinion:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263818/using-google-analytics-asynchnonous-code-from-external-js-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't *exactly* what Google suggests.

Basically, you can instantiate GA as early as possible -- that's the part that says:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
```

The rest of it, you can load at the bottom of the page.

You can even put the `_gaq =...;` in an external file at the top of the page, and then the rest of it at the bottom.

The goal is this:

Google makes _gaq an array at the beginning.  Then you use the array's `.push(...);` method to add tracking to the array (really, you're just adding arrays of strings).

When you add the second part of the code, at the bottom of the page, it's saving the data that's inside of the `_gaq` array, to a holding array.  Then it's turning `_gaq` into a real-live program, where `.push(...);` from now on, on the page, actually sends data and whatnot.

And on initial-load of the full file, `_gaq` will run through the array of pushed instructions and turn that into a server-call.

They suggest starting `_gaq` as high on the page as possible, so that you can add user-based tracking to the page, or to buttons, or whatever...  ...so that when the program finally ***does*** load at the bottom of the page, all of those actions that you've added via `_gaq.push(["_method", "data"]);` will be tracked by GA, when it's running, so you don't miss any events.

Now, you don't want to put both the `_gaq =...` part of the code, ***AND*** the script-download part of the code at the top of the page.  Downloading scripts takes a while.
GA is doing it the right way, and is loading it asynchronously, which is perfect...  ...but you can still clean it up by moving the second half to the bottom of your page (or putting it in an external script).

So the answer ends up being, yes, feel 100% free to move the GA code into external scripts, that's not going to change a single thing about how it runs.

But you should still consider leaving the external script for `_gaq=...` at the top (so that if you're tracking user-behaviour to custom events, you can do that as soon as the page is ready -- but then why put that in an external script, when it will take time to load and execute, versus the actually assignment, which will take microseconds, even on slow browsers?).

And then move the script call down the page (or move it into an external file, which is referenced at the bottom of your page).

Comment: Thanks my main concern was working and the fact that I am calling both parts in the samee external file.

Comment: Neither of those are much of a concern.  And if all you're going to do is call "_trackPageView" it doesn't really matter.  If you're looking to do more, then do what I suggested.  ***OH*** and I should mention that the one other thing that you should do when you define the `_gaq =...` is you should do a `_gaq.push()` to set your account.  Again, if all you're doing is tracking pageviews, it doesn't matter.  If none of your calls are user-based events, then it doesn't matter, either.  Just set accounts up before you start doing things like: `button.onclick=function() { _gaq.push(...); };`