# Google Analytics in external js file not reporting

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, google-api

According to Google Analytics our account is receiving data. I uploaded to our [**Alpha site here**](http://neytiri.whoat.net/) on Monday and so far I can only see 1 visit on the 19th and nothing for the rest of the week, I had people from other offices and other states visit the site :(

[image]

Curious if you may see something obviously wrong with the code below:
Everything looks good, even the Search term tracking works (consoles out the term)

```
//GOOGLE ANALYTICS
//======================================================================
WHOAT.analytics = (function ($, w, undefined) {
'use strict';

//initial google setup
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.lang = 'en';
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxx-x']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'whoat.net']);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', false]);
_gaq.push(['_gat._anonymizeIp']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

// console.log('inside Analytics');
console.log(_gaq);

function init() {
    (function () {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);

        console.log(ga);
    }());
}

//TRACK PAGE VIEWS
var trackPageView = function (url) {
    //get the url from the pathname if it wasn't passed in
    if (url === null || url === undefined) {
        url = w.location.pathname;
    }
    //if an id is part of the url, replace the id with 'details'
    url = url.replace(new RegExp(/\/[0-9]+$/), '/details');
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', url]);

    console.log('analytics trackPageView: '+url);
};

//TRACK SEARCH EVENT
var trackSearchEvent = function (searchTerm) {
    var url = w.location.pathname;
    url = url.replace(new RegExp(/\/[0-9]+$/), '/details');
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'search', searchTerm, 'url for search is ' + url]);

    console.log('analytics trackSearchEvent: '+searchTerm);
};

//TRACK VIDEO EVENT
var trackVideoEvent = function (event, videoID, time) {
    var label;
    if (time !== null && time !== undefined) {
        label = 'video id is ' + videoID + " and time is " + time;
    } else {
        label = 'video id is ' + videoID;
    }

    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'video', event, label]);
};

//track the page just landed on
trackPageView();

return {
    trackPageView: trackPageView,
    trackSearchEvent : trackSearchEvent,
    trackVideoEvent : trackVideoEvent,
    init : init
};
}(jQuery, window));

$(document).ready(function () {
    WHOAT.analytics.init();
}); // document ready
```

Our Alpha site here: http://neytiri.whoat.net/

The console.logs read out, and no errors (besides the vimeo one)

Comment: This may be what I need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263818/using-google-analytics-asynchnonous-code-from-external-js-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to move the var `_gaq = _gaq || [];` 
and all the `_gaq` variables outside of the closure. So above the `//GOOGLE ANALYTICS` 
Works perfectly now :)

[image]

[Brian's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263818/using-google-analytics-asynchnonous-code-from-external-js-file) is what fixed this.