# dynamically loaded google analytics not working

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to load Google Analytics code dynamically from an external javascript file.
Every HTML file loads the js file so I figured it would be better to load it that way than manually pasting it to every page.

the js file code looks like this:

```
// wait for page to load
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  loadAna();
});

// load google analytics
function loadAna(){

  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'my UA key here', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

  window.console && console.log("anaytics loaded to "+location.pathname.substring(1));
}
```

The console shows that the function is being ran, but Google tells me "The Google Analytics tracking code has not been detected on your website's home page".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where in Google are you seeing this? Is this in your GA account?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different, safer approach verified by others. For example you can use an external script that you would reference like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/google-analytics.js" ></script>
```

And then put your code in the external file. This way you can easily include the same script on multiple pages without duplication.

For an example check out:

[Using Google Analytics asynchronous code from external JS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263818/using-google-analytics-asynchronous-code-from-external-js-file)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I just didn't wait long enough.
I checked the next day and analytics was working.
It just must take some time to start.