# Google Analytics event tracking JS runs / works in dev console but not from ex file

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-analytics

My google analytics javascript events work perfect from within the developer console. **But** they do not work at all when included on the page from an external js file.. *for some reason.*

For example; **below will run when included in the console. But will not when included in a separate external js file**. eg.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/gascript.js"></script>
```

Not I have also tried moving the include to 3 different areas within the head and footer locations. I have also tried including the script within various versions of 'on dom ready'

For example, GA event tracking JS inside `/gascript.js`

---

```
$(function() {
  $('.like').click(function() { // good song, thumbs up
      var SongTitle = $('.like-data h2').text();        
      var date = new Date();
      var month = date.getUTCMonth() + 1;
      var day = date.getUTCDate();
      var year = date.getUTCFullYear();
      var time = date.toLocaleTimeString();
      var formattedDate = month + '/' + day + '/' + year + '|' + time;    
     ga('send', 'event', SongTitle, 'Like', formattedDate);
  });
});
```

full html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="root" ng-controller="IndexCtrl">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title ng-bind="pageTitle"></title>

        <!-- Favicon -->
        <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.png" />

        <!-- CSS Libraries -->
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/carousel.css">-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->

        <!-- CSS Core -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>

        <!-- Pre-load-required JS Libraries -->
        <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Modified carousel plugin -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="plugins/3DSlider/css/style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/3DSlider/js/modernizr.custom.53451.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/3DSlider/js/jquery.gallery.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body ng-click="clickBody()">

<!-- modular HTML components here -->

        <!-- Angular Files -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-soundmanager2/dist/angular-soundmanager2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/bootstrap/modal.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/gascript.js"></script><!-- here -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/directives.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/filters.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/services.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/services2.js"></script>

        <script>
          (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
          (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
          m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
          })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Also note, I am including GA within my app through UI router injection method.**

**eg.**

http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/11/07/AngularJS-Google-Analytics-with-the-UI-Router.aspx

Comment: Were you able to fix your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess is that the target elements `.like` do not exist in the DOM, when the script is run. This means that the `click` event is not binding to anything; this is also why you are able to run the script when pasted into the console (at that point, the `.like` elements do exist).

Perhaps try event delegation:

```
$('body').on('click', '.like', callbackFunction);
```

See "Direct and delegated events": http://jqapi.com/#p=on

Using event delegation will make sure the event fires for descendant elements of `body`, in this case `.click` elements.  The click event will fire even if more descendant elements are added in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the *www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js* is not being loaded before the *gascripts.js* . Dev console prevents script cache by default & forces loading scripts completely before the page functions are evaluated, this may be the reason why this is working..

Have you tried putting the google analytics js code in the `<head>` section ?

In addition, it would be safe to check for a valid ***ga*** object , before performing operations on it. (window.ga or $window.ga )

[Using Google Analytics asynchronous code from external JS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263818/using-google-analytics-asynchronous-code-from-external-js-file)